# How to visualize a complex function using vector fields?

Tags: complex-numbers, vector-fields

I am asked to graph the vector field of $w=f(z)=iz$.

So my two variables function is $w=-y+ix$.

If my input is for example $(1,1)$ my output is $(-1,i)$ but $i=(0,1)$ right?
I'm not really familiar with vector fields I just used Wikipedia's article to understand the concept, however I'm not sure how to apply this to a complex function.

Can anyone please explain this problem?

Comment: multiplication by $i$ gives you a 90 degrees rotation of the plane

Comment: if $z=1+i$ then $iz=-1+i$ is the correct calculation

Comment: @janmarqz oh! I understand how this works now. Thank you so much!!

Comment: glad to be useful